# Saving Session Data is not working . SESSIONS IN PHP

Tags: php, html

This code is supposed to save data after i click on save button, but it is not saving , any ideas what is happening?

The script name is : prueba.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $save=$_POST['save'];
```

This part is the function to calculate the addition of the two inputs

```
 function calculate_price($cart)
 {

  $price = 0.0;

     if(is_array($cart))
     {

             foreach($cart as $isbn => $qty)
             {

                 $price +=$qty;
              }

      }
   return $price;
  }
```

This is , if the button save is not clicked

```
   if(!$save)    
  {

  $cart=array("jonathan" => 30, "andrea" => 40);

  $_SESSION["cart"]=$cart;
  }
```

this is in case we click the " save " button

```
  if($save)    
  {

    foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $isbn => $qty) 

    {
             echo " ISBN : ".$isbn;
        if($qty=="0")
            { echo "borraste";
             unset($_SESSION["cart"][$isbn]);}
         else
            $_SESSION["cart"][$isbn] =$qty; 

     }


   }
```

This is the form that i use to enter values , so it can be changed after click on " save "

```
   foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $isbn => $qty)
      {

   ?>
        <table>
        <form action ="prueba.php" method ="post">
        <tr>
        <td>Value of <?php echo $isbn ?></td>
        <td><input type = "text" name ="<?php $isbn ?>" value ="<?php echo $_SESSION["cart"]        [$isbn] ?>" size ="3"></td>
        </tr>
  <?php
        }



    ?>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"></td></tr>

        </form></table>

   <?php
```

This is just to check if the session exist and has values on the array

```
   if($_SESSION['cart']&&array_count_values($_SESSION['cart']))
   {
   $_SESSION["total_price"] = calculate_price($_SESSION["cart"]);
   echo "The total amount is :  ".$_SESSION["total_price"];

   }

   ?>
```

i'D really appreciate your help in checking this and see a solution for this , i guess the mistake could be on the form? , thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your not getting your post values. And a much better solution is to create a grouping array name so that its easier to manage. Ex: `qty[<?php echo $isbn; ?>]`. Here is a [**working sample**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jI8bWg):

```
// initial setup
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array("jonathan" => 30, "andrea" => 40);
}

if(isset($_POST['save'])) { // is button is saved
    $qty = $_POST['qty']; // get the grouping array
    foreach($qty as $isbn => $value) { // loop it
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$isbn])) { // so now you can use they keys as isbn
            if($value == 0) { // if zero then unset
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$isbn]);
                continue;
            }
            $_SESSION['cart'][$isbn] = $value; // if not then set qty
        }

    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <table border="0">
        <?php foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $isbn => $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Value of <?php echo $isbn; ?></td>
            <td>
                <input style="text-align: center;" type="text" name="qty[<?php echo $isbn; ?>]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" size="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div class="total">
    <!-- total -->
    <p>The total is: <?php echo array_sum($_SESSION['cart']); ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this one worked perfectly, i might need to adjust it to the original script i have but great answer

Comment: sure @LuisRevilla glad this helped, i just refactored it a bit to make some sense on some parts.

Comment: GREAT!!!!! it worked in my main script now , wow i really appreciate yuor huge help !! i spent almost 2 days working on it ^^

Answer (score 0):

There were few errors in your code
firstly you were printing form action inside a loop which leads to invalid html code
and secondly while storing the data in the session you are using old values which are already present in the cookie
I have modified the code and tested it

```
             <?php
             session_start();
             $save=$_POST['save'];

             function calculate_price($cart)
             {

              $price = 0.0;

                 if(is_array($cart))
                 {

                         foreach($cart as $isbn => $qty)
                         {
                             echo $qty . "<br>";
                             $price +=$qty;
                          }

                  }
               return $price;
              }


              if(!$save)    
              {
              $cart=array("jonathan" => 30, "andrea" => 40);

              $_SESSION["cart"]=$cart;
              }

             if($save)    
              {
                $cart=array("jonathan" => $_POST['jonathan'], "andrea" => $_POST['andrea']);
                foreach($cart as $isbn => $qty) 

                {
                         echo " ISBN : ".$isbn;
                    if($qty=="0")
                        { echo "borraste";
                         unset($_SESSION["cart"][$isbn]);}
                     else
                     {
                        //$cart=array($isbn => $qty);
                        $_SESSION["cart"][$isbn] = $qty; 
                        echo $qty;

                     }

                 }

               }
               ?>


                <form action ="prueba.php" method ="post">
                    <table>
              <?php

              foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $isbn => $qty)
                  {

               ?>

                    <tr>
                    <td>Value of <?php echo $isbn ?></td>
                    <td><input type = "text" name ="<?php echo $isbn ?>" value ="<?php echo $_SESSION["cart"]        [$isbn] ?>" size ="3"></td>
                    </tr>
              <?php
                    }



                ?>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"></td></tr>
                    </table>
                    </form>

               <?php

               if($_SESSION['cart'] && array_count_values($_SESSION['cart']))
               {
               $_SESSION["total_price"] = calculate_price($_SESSION["cart"]);
               echo "The total amount is :  ".$_SESSION["total_price"];

               }

               ?>
```

Comment: Mmmm not sure , i tested this code that fortunatly is similar to my format script , but for me is still not working

Comment: I tested it on wamp and it was working fine and infact the chosen answer wasn't working lol maybe coz I am running it on localhost